# why AsyncTask Connection Does not return anything?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask class which connects to a localurl. the connection does not return any exception. infact when i run the code below on eclipse as a normal java project it runs perfectly fine.

the code in android studio:

```
package parsa.lop.adjust;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class SendDietInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private PatientMain activity;

    public SendDietInfo(PatientMain activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.0.3/a.php/");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            while(reader.ready()){
                str.append(reader.readLine());
            }
            String s = str.toString();
            reader.close();
            System.out.println(s);
            return s+",,,";
        }catch(Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        activity.sendDietInfoDone(s);
    }
}
```

and in address `http://10.0.0.3/a.php/` lies

```
<?php
echo "hello world"

?>
```

how is it that the interior code in `doInBackground` method works perfectly fine in eclipse and returns hello world but android studio doesn't. i have add that i have added internet permission and there is no exception happening meanwhile. the problem is just that the hello world doesn't get returned. an empty string is printed.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the line:

```
while(reader.ready()){
     str.append(reader.readLine());
}
```

I just changed it to:

```
while((temp = reader.readLine())!= null){
     str.append(temp);
}
```

apparently the interpreter that android runs is different from jvm. and ready() function is not working the same as it does in jvm.